# Merging records from one spreadsheet into another

Tags: vba, excel, time-limit-exceeded, join

I have created the code below that compare two spreadsheets . It initially compares the range of value from sheet1 ("Status") to sheet2 ("Interface") . Whenever a range matches with the ranges present in other sheet , it does nothing .When the range does not any matches in the other sheet , then the entire record is copied from sheet2 to sheet1 . I have around 1500 rows of data in both sheets with 15 columns . It takes around 30 minutes . 
. I look forward to see If I could get any help.

```
 Option Explicit

Function UpdateNEW() As Long
'   This Sub will do the Following Update
'   Run through all records in NEW
'      if found in Steps ---> Do nothing
'      if not found in Steps ----> Add it to Steps
'

Dim WSO As Worksheet
Dim WSN As Worksheet
Dim MaxRowO As Long, MaxRowN As Long, I As Long, J As Long, lAdd As Long
Dim sJob As String, sOps As String, sFirstAddress As String
Dim cCell As Range
Dim bNotFound As Boolean


'---> Disable Events
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'---> Set Variables
Set WSO = Sheets("Steps")
Set WSN = Sheets("Interface")
MaxRowO = WSO.Range("A" & WSO.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MaxRowN = WSN.Range("C" & WSN.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
WSN.Range("P6:P" & MaxRowN).ClearContents

'---> Loop thruough all rows in sheet New
For I = 6 To MaxRowN
    bNotFound = False
    sJob = WSN.Cells(I, "D")
    sOps = WSN.Cells(I, "E")
    Set cCell = WSO.Range("B2:B" & MaxRowO).Find(what:=sJob, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not cCell Is Nothing Then
        bNotFound = True
        sFirstAddress = cCell.Address
        Do
            '---> Check to See if Ops if found for that Job
            If WSO.Cells(cCell.Row, "C") = sOps Then
                bNotFound = False
                Exit Do
            End If
            Set cCell = WSO.Range("B2:C" & MaxRowO).FindNext(cCell)
        Loop While Not cCell Is Nothing And cCell.Address <> sFirstAddress
    Else
        bNotFound = True
    End If

    '---> Add Record to OLD if Not Found
    If bNotFound Then
        WSN.Range("C" & I & ":O" & I).Copy WSO.Range("A" & MaxRowO + 1)
        'WSN.Range("P" & I) = "Copied to OLD"
        'WSO.Range("N" & MaxRowO + 1) = sJob & " " & sOps & " Copied from New row " & I
        MaxRowO = MaxRowO + 1
        lAdd = lAdd + 1
    End If


Next I

'---> Enable Events
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

UpdateNEW = lAdd

End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to [codereview.se]! Your title probably applies to about half the code posted here. Please [edit] it to describe in a few words _what your code does_ not what kind of help you're looking for. The "halp make it fasterzzz!!!" part belongs in the text of the question, as you currently have it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unique data could be appended, using a Scripting Dictionary and arrays in less than a second.  Alternatively, you could use an ADO Query to append records from sheet1, not in sheet2.

The easiest method would be to add all the records to the second worksheet then record a macro that:

- Convert the range to a table
- Select a cell in the range then click Ribbon >  Table Tools > Remove Duplicates

All that is left to do is refactor the Macro to make the code dynamic.

Watch:
 - [Excel VBA Introduction Part 25 - Arrays](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=h9FTX7TgkpM&index=28&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)
 - [Excel VBA Introduction Part 39 - Dictionaries](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=dND4coLI_B8&index=43&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)
 - [Excel VBA Introduction Part 32 - ADO (ActiveX Data Objects) SQL Statements (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=-c2QvyPpkAM&index=36&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

---

Here is how I would rewrite the OP's code using a Scripting Dictionary and arrays.

```
Function UpdateNEW2() As Long
    Const Delimiter As String = "|"
    Dim dic As Object
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim newRows As Range
    Dim vSteps, key
    With Sheets("Steps")
        vSteps = .Range("A2:O2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value
    End With

    Dim r As Long, c As Long, n As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(vSteps)
        key = vSteps(r, 3) & Delimiter & vSteps(r, 4)
        Debug.Print key
        If Not dic.Exists(key) Then dic.Add key, 0
    Next

    Dim vInterface, results
    With Sheets("Interface")
        vInterface = .Range("A7:O7", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Value
    End With

    ReDim results(1 To UBound(vInterface), 1 To 15)
    For r = 1 To UBound(vInterface)
        key = vInterface(r, 4) & Delimiter & vInterface(r, 5)
        Debug.Print key
        If Not dic.Exists(key) Then
            n = n + 1
            For c = 3 To 15
                results(n, c - 2) = vInterface(r, c)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    If n > 0 Then
        With Sheets("Steps")
            With .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
               .Resize(n, 15).Value = results
            End With
        End With
    End If
    UpdateNEW2 = n
End Function
```

([Sample Data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kVU1NobGBaVO2Jk3vucIcrMcecD-C-QU))

Comment: Thanks . I am new to VBA . If possible could you indicate lines where the codes can be modified . It would be of great help .

Comment: @JohnPattrick I added some untested code.  Sorry, but I didn't add any comments.  Let me know where you get the errors...lol.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts . While I am executing the code , I get Run Time Error 1004 on the code      ->      .Resize(n, 15).Value = results

Comment: @JohnPattrick it probably didn't return any results.  Can you link me the file?

Comment: I have uploaded a sample worksheet of the original file . When pasted , the highlighted ones should be below the rest of file .

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kVU1NobGBaVO2Jk3vucIcrMcecD-C-QU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JohnPattrick I updated my answer.  I didn't notice that the data starts on row 7 of Interface.  Unless you have a compelling reason to do otherwise, it is better to start your data in A1 for consistency.  I also didn't bother with: `WSN.Range("P6:P" & MaxRowN).ClearContents`

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort  . It worked .

Comment: @JohnPattrick Sweet!!  How long does it take to run?

Comment: It takes now around 1 to 3 min to execute compared to last time when it took more than 15 min to execute.

Comment: I have one small doubt . Is there any way ,we can make the function does not work when the sheets are empty . It can indicate that sheet is empty kinda of thing

Comment: 1 to 3 min is a ridiculous amount of time for that little amount of data.   You should add the "Disable Events" and "Enable Events" parts of the code to the procedure.

Comment: Small Help . Could you explain your code . It works , I just wanted to learn how it executes